# Laravel routes/web.php how does Auth::routes() calls register/login/home page?

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to laravel, still learning how the framework works.

I installed laravel Auth following this to tutorial https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication

It created few views and controllers, as well as modified the web.php

My question is that im not being able to get my head around on how `Auth::routes` points to these url `mysite.com/register`, `mysite.com/login`.

From every tutorial I have going through, in order to specify a url you need to add it to web.php. so for example if I want to connect to contact-us in this url `mysite.com/contact-us`, I will have to alter my web.php to something like:

```
Route::post('contact-us', 'MyController@MyFunction');
```

But when I installed Laravel Auth, it just added this to my web.php:

```
Auth::routes();
```

This `Auth::routes();` allows me to connect to mysite.com/register, mysite.com/login. How does it do it?

This is the default installation progress for Laravel 6, so i will not post any code regarding the above, as I believe anyone with a lot of experience knows what I am talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Auth::routes() is the shorthand for the following routes.

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');

// Email Verification Routes...
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
```

So either you can use the above routes in your `web.php` file or you can use the shorthand helper function for those routes. you can check this [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1149) for more understanding about routing in laravel

Answer (score 2):

To make it more complete, if you want to remove some Auth::routes, you can use something like this:

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

Answer (score 0):

it handles that via traits and comes up to `YourProject\vendor\laravel\ui\src\AuthRouteMethods.php`then to your `YourProject\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php`
where there is `use RegistersUsers` trait and then up to
`YourProject\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\RegistersUsers.php`
But the changing package files' content  of Laravel core is a bad practice. Its ok merely  for tracing purpose of whats going on under the hood